# Delete row when cell is not equal a string in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through an array and, when it finds a cell which is not equal a specific value, it deletes the entire row. Here is the code:

```
Sub DeleteTest()

Dim crr()

crr = Range("A3:A1000")

For i = LBound(crr, 1) To UBound(crr, 1)
    If (crr(i, 1) <> "One" And crr(i, 1) <> "Two") Then
       ' Line to delete the row in which the value of the cell is not One or Two

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I know I can also do it with an Autofilter, but I would like to know the way to do it with the array.

Comment: Create a union of the row numbers then delete all the rows at once after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Sub DeleteTest()

    Dim rng As Range, crr(), i As Long

    Set rng = Range("A3:A1000")
    crr = rng.Value

    For i = UBound(crr, 1) To LBound(crr, 1) Step -1 '<<< loop backwards
        If (crr(i, 1) <> "One" And crr(i, 1) <> "Two") Then
           rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! The code worked. What would be the reason to loop backwards? Is it the same as introducing "For i = LBound(crr, 1) To UBound(crr, 1)"?

Comment: If you start by deleting row 1, then where does row 2 go?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim x, r As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = .Range("A3:A1000")
    x = Filter(.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(IF((" & r.Address & "=""One"")+(" & r.Address & "=""Two""),""A"" & ROW(" & r.Address & ")))"), False, False)
    If UBound(x) = -1 Then Exit Sub
    .Range(Join(x, ",")).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    On Error Resume Next
        r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Rows.Hidden = False
End With
End Sub
```